# Perl : How to read file lines(CSV File) into Hash keys and sort them out into ascending order then write them out into new sorted CSV File

Tags: csv, sorting, perl, hash

So I'm processing this CSV File but the problem is The CSV file seems to be sorted by the first column for each row that is returned but not based on any of the other columns in the same row.I want to sort this into ascending order line by line not just by the first column somewhat to normalize them.

The content of the CSV file looks like this (you can download the csv file from here https://www4.palmettogba.com/pdac_dmecs/searchProductClassificationResults.do?manufacturer=&codeDecision=&productName=&modelNumber=&classification=Surgical+Dressings)
[image]

What I have in mind is this to read file lines(CSV File) into Hash keys and sort them out into ascending order then write them out into new sorted CSV File. but I dont have the skill to do this on perl, I really need to do this on perl as I making a script for conver csv file into tsv then into HTML but first I want to sort the csv file before I process it.

what I have in mind is
Read file lines into hash key $HASH($line_contents) =1;
Sort Hash Keys (foreach my $oneline (sort keys %HASH))
As looping through the sorted keys, write keys out to a new sorted CSV file.

```
#CHECK IF CSV FILE DOWNLOAD IS FINISHED
my $complete_download_flag = 0;

while($complete_download_flag == 0)
{
    my @download_directory = read_dir($download_dir_link);
    foreach my $downloaded_file (@download_directory)
    {
        if($downloaded_file =~ /\QProduct Classification List.csv\E/sgi)
        {
            $complete_download_flag = 1;
        }
    }
    sleep(5);
}
#SORTED CONTENTS OF CSV BEFORE CONVERSION function to put here
print "sORTING csv content...\n";

#CONVERT CSV TO TSV
print "Converting csv to tsv...\n";
my $csv = Text::CSV->new ({ binary => 1 });
my $tsv = Text::CSV->new ({ binary => 1, sep_char => "\t", eol => "\n"});

open my $infh,  "<:encoding(utf8)", "$download_dir_link/Product Classification List.csv";
open my $outfh, ">:encoding(utf8)", "Product Classification List.tsv";

while (my $row = $csv->getline ($infh))
{
    $tsv->print ($outfh, $row);
}
close($infh);
close($outfh);

my $tsv_content = "";
open(my $fh, '<', "Product Classification List.tsv");
while (<$fh>)
{
    $tsv_content = $tsv_content.$_;
}
close($fh);
print "Conversion complete! cleaning tsv content...\n";
```

Comment: Perhaps [`Text::CSV`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Text::CSV) can be of help

Comment: "what I have in mind is Read file lines into hash key $HASH($line_contents) =1; Sort Hash Keys (foreach my $oneline (sort keys %HASH)) As looping through the sorted keys, write keys out to a new sorted CSV file" Sounds good to me.

Comment: When you use hash keys you risk overwriting data if the keys are identical. I don't think that would be agreeable to you. You don't need a hash to sort csv.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(First, when I exported the data as CSV using your link, the saved file had a couple of extra lines at the top; everything that follows assumes you deleted those.)

A number of approaches:

Since this seems like a simple CSV file with no multi-line records, just sort it using the standard `sort(1)` utility, either before processing the file in perl:

```sh
$ (head -1 "Product Classification List.csv"; sed "1d" "Product Classification List.csv" | sort) > sorted.csv
```

Or, using the often-handy [`Text::AutoCSV`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Text::AutoCSV) to convert from CSV to TSV and sort all in `perl` (This can easily be adapted to a one-liner, too):

```perl
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use warnings;
use strict;
use Text::AutoCSV;

# Original CSV file and output TSV file are command-line arguments, not
# hard-coded.

Text::AutoCSV->new(in_file => $ARGV[0], encoding => "UTF-8", out_file
                   => $ARGV[1], out_sep_char => "\t", out_orderby => [
                   "PRODUCTNAME", "MANUFACTURERDISTRIBUTOR",
                   "MODELNUMBER"," HCPCSCODE", "EFFECTIVEBEGINDATE",
                   "EFFECTIVEENDDATE", "COMMENTS" ])->write;
```

Or using [csvkit](https://csvkit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) from a command line to sort and convert:

```sh
$ csvsort "Product Classification List.csv" | csvformat -T > sorted.tsv
```

Comment: I do have a question Shawn, I need the function to be inserted before I convert the CSV file into TSV and later on into HTML file, the above suggestion works to but not in my case I guess ? The script that I made is scraping a website(the link of the CSV file) theres a hundred of CSV file on that website , I sorted it out the function for those , my only problem is the output that i'm getting is not arranged into ascending format , its somewhat messed up it only sorted by the first column, so what I need is before my CSV to TSV conversion I want the CSV to be sorted into ascending format.

Comment: before I processed it into TSV. Do you have and idea on how to do that ? thank you

Comment: As you notice also the CSV from the website is not arranged into ascending format is somehow sorted only by first column dynamically .

Comment: @johndenverabella Yes, and all of these sort it.

Comment: (And two of them convert to TSV. Instead of one script that does everything, break it up into smaller steps and chain them all together).